# How to get values from multiple columns as IEnumerable using SqlKata (Dapper)

Tags: c#, sql, dapper, sqlkata

I'm using SQL and I have a table shown below in my DB.

```
Id   Remark1    Remark2    Remark3    Remark4    
------------------------------------------------
1    AAA        BBB        CCC        DDD      
2    EEE        FFF        GGG        HHH
```

How can I get all the values from `Remark*` columns as `IEnumerable<string>` using the following DTO?

```
class MyDTO
{
   public int ID { get; }
   public IEnumerable<string> Remarks { get; }
}
```

NOTE: I'm using SqlKata (Dapper), which you can also use when answering.

Comment: Are you looking to map just those 4 columns to a collection, or does your real use case have many more columns to deal with?

Comment: @John H My actual table has 50 `Remark` columns!

Comment: Are you using SqlServer?

Comment: @amd I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Dapper, maybe just use the non-generic Query API. This returns each row as `dynamic`, but this can also be cast to `IDictionary<string,object>`, which allows you to access each named column (for example, via `foreach`).

````cs
foreach (IDictionary<string, object> row in conn.Query(sql, args))
{
    var obj = new MyDto();
    var vals = new List<string>();
    obj.Remarks = list;
    foreach ((var key, var value) in row)
    {
        if (key == nameof(obj.Id))
            obj.Id = (int)value;
        else
            vals.Add((string)value);
    }
    // do something with obj
}
```
````

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is almost exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to create an ugly looking - but working - UNION ALL query:

```
SELECT Id, Remark1 as Remark FROM Table
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, Remark2 as Remark FROM Table
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, Remark... as Remark FROM Table
```

That's can be done in a for..loop using SqlKata, calling the Union inside the loop

https://sqlkata.com/docs/combine#union-except-intersect

Non-Tested code sample:

```
var q = new Query("Table").Select("Id", "Remark1 as Remark");
for(int r=2;r<=50;i++)
{
  var u = new Query("Table").Select("Id", $"Remark{r} as Remark");
  q = q.Union(u);
}
```